# Java persistence (Ebean) serialize generated value to Json

Tags: java, json, orm, persistence, ebean

I have two entities and OneToMany relationship between them. First:

```
@Entity
public class Trip extends Model {

    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

The second one:

```
@Entity
public class Category extends Model {

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    public Trip trip;
}
```

So, Ebean automatically generates the `trip_id` column for the `Category` table.

Now I need to serialize `Category` entity/object to JSON (with `trip_id` including). How can I do it? I was trying to manually create `trip_id` field, but received the duplicate exception.

Answer (score 0):

You have one-directional relations. You should change them to bi-directional. So there should be:

```
@Entity
public class Trip extends Model {

    ...

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="trip")
    public List<Category> categories = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Category extends Model {

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    public Trip trip;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="category")
    public List<Place> places = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class Place extends Model {

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    public Category category;

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand how it helps to serialize 'trip_id' to JSON. Maybe my question wasn't clear. I need to send the 'Trip' object  converted to JSON over HTTP. And 'trip_id' attribute should be there (not the whole 'Trip'). I've already solved it by some workaround, but maybe there is a better way. Btw, I already have the bidirectional relation here, just pasted the wrong piece of code, sorry :) edited my question.